# Change the heading for endnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes, endnotes

I'm using `endnotes` package to move all my footnotes to the end of the document. Is it possible to change the title of the endnotes list from "Notes" to "Endnote"? I'm also interest to find a way to change the formate of the list (like adding an indent after each number).

For illustration I want to to make my endnotes looks like these:

[image: desired formate]

For now, the `endnotes` package give me this result:

[image]

Thank you in advance,,,

Comment: Do you mean: `\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The renaming of the *Notes* name is easily done by `\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes}`, see the comment by Jon.

The numbering is a little bit trickier. The documentation is not very helpful, but the code of `endnotes.sty` provides some clue.

The endnotes marker at the end are typeset using `\@makeenmark`

```
\def\@makeenmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}},
```

which clearly states that the marker is a superscript. If this is not wanted, the `\@textsuperscript` must be changed to something different. A patch would work, however, this patch must be done **after** the inline notes markers are set, otherwise it would be printed as `1.` to, not as `^1` etc.

For simple purposes,  following code prepends the `\theendnotes` (responsible for printing the notes at the end) with the patching code for the marker:

```
\xpretocmd{\theendnotes}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\@makeenmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}{\hbox{\normalfont\theenmark.\space}}{}{}
  }{}{}
```

This is injected into some sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\theendnotes}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\@makeenmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}{%
   \hbox{\normalfont\theenmark.\space}%
 }{}{}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\endnote{By Harpo}
\blindtext\endnote{By Groucho}
\blindtext\endnote{By Gummo}
\blindtext\endnote{By Chico}
\blindtext\endnote{By Zeppo}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing two `%` inside `\pretocmd`.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work with the current version of `endnotes`.