# Endnotes are not linked

Tags: hyperref, endnotes

The endnotes in my document are not linked.

1. How can I link `endnotes` and back to the original page?
2. How can I set the title of `theendnotes` to zero without a vertical space?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\endnote=\endnote{}
\def\enotesize{\footnotesize}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{section}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This is the first Article 1}

\textbf{Hello all!} In this collection of different articles I need to put the footnotes to the end of each article. But these footnotes are not linked, and I would like to have also the backreference to the page of origine. Is this possible? Supplemental question: How to avoid the ``Title'' of endnotes and the resulting space, setting it to none with 

\verb!\renewcommand{\notesname}{}! \endnote{comp. \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238403/change-the-heading-for-endnotes}}

While editing this posting, I discovered the package \verb!endnotes-hy! Perhaps the solution? \endnote{comp. /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endnotes-hy/endnotes-hy.sty}

\blindtext\endnote{third footnote}

\subsection{First Subsection 1.1}

\blindtext\endnote{fourth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{fifth footnote}

\subsection{Second Subsection 1.2}

\blindtext\endnote{sixth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{seventh footnote}

\subsubsection{Here a Subsubsection 1.2.1}

\blindtext\endnote{eighth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{ninth footnote}

\subsection{Annotations}

\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 0pt
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\section{This is the second Article 2}
\blindtext\endnote{first footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{second footnote}

\subsection{Annotations}

\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 0pt
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE stands for **Minimal** Working Example - could you please remove the unnecessary code such as `komafonts`, comments etc and minimize it down to just the issue please?

Comment: With `endnotes` you can get hyperlinks for *labeled* notes with `endnotes-hy`. But if you want backlinks too, then you need either `enotez` or `postnotes`. This summary is perhaps useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669532/105447.

Comment: @gusbers thx for this suggestion: I will try the coming week your `postnotes` and perhaps `enotez`.

Comment: And sorry for the too long MWE. I will edit it tomorrow, to strip it down.

Comment: I shortened my MWE. Hope it is compiling again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `endnotes` package, you can use the `endnotes-hy` to get hyperlinks for *labeled* notes from the mark to the text, but no backlinks.

With `endnotes` + `endnotes-hy` a document should look like:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{endnotes-hy}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% You can remove the heading with:
\renewcommand{\enoteheading}{}

\begin{document}

\endnote{Foo.}\label{en:1}

% Non-labeled notes are not linked.
\endnote{Bar.}

\clearpage{}

% And there are no backlinks.
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

However, since you require backlinks too, the only packages that offer this are `enotez` and `postnotes`.  With `enotez` you could setup things as:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{enotez}
% Enabling backlinks.
\setenotez{backref}
% You could remove the notes heading with:
% \DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{heading=}
% But I think you'd do better by letting the package do its job for you:
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{
  heading=\subsection{Annotations}}

\counterwithin*{endnote}{section}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This is the first Article 1}

\blindtext\endnote{first footnote}

\blindtext\endnote{second footnote}

\blindtext\endnote{third footnote}

\subsection{First Subsection 1.1}

\blindtext\endnote{fourth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{fifth footnote}

\subsection{Second Subsection 1.2}

\blindtext\endnote{sixth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{seventh footnote}

\subsubsection{Here a Subsubsection 1.2.1}

\blindtext\endnote{eighth footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{ninth footnote}

\printendnotes

\section{This is the second Article 2}
\blindtext\endnote{first footnote}
\blindtext\endnote{second footnote}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

And with `postnotes`:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{postnotes}
% You could remove the notes heading with:
% \postnotesetup{heading=}
% But I think you'd do better by letting the package do its job for you:
\postnotesetup{heading=\subsection{Annotations}}

\counterwithin*{postnote}{section}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This is the first Article 1}

\blindtext\postnote{first footnote}

\blindtext\postnote{second footnote}

\blindtext\postnote{third footnote}

\subsection{First Subsection 1.1}

\blindtext\postnote{fourth footnote}
\blindtext\postnote{fifth footnote}

\subsection{Second Subsection 1.2}

\blindtext\postnote{sixth footnote}
\blindtext\postnote{seventh footnote}

\subsubsection{Here a Subsubsection 1.2.1}

\blindtext\postnote{eighth footnote}
\blindtext\postnote{ninth footnote}

\printpostnotes

\section{This is the second Article 2}
\blindtext\postnote{first footnote}
\blindtext\postnote{second footnote}

\printpostnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you gusbrs. Great answer! I will stick to your package :-)