# How to create the equivalent of a bibliography for physical locations?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, addresses

I would like to reference addresses throughout a document and as an appendix generate a list with all the address entries used and the link to the places in the document where they were used.

Just like it is done with a bibliography.

I'm actually thinking it'd be the easiest to use a special kind of entry and store them in a bib file, and then use it as a list of citations.

How would you do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use a bib file with `@misc` entries and if necessary a custom bst if one of the standard ones does not produce what you need

Comment: `biblatex` allows to define not only the output but also the data interface and the data source mapping. For both, `bibtex` and `biblatex`/`biber` there already exist examples for, e.g., managing address databases instead of bibliographies. See, e.g., [`directory`](https://ctan.org/pkg/directory) or Ulrike Fischer's article [biblatex variations](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111fischer.pdf)

Comment: Depending on how you want the in-text references to look you could also consider a list of endnotes with backreferences (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675030/endnotes-are-not-linked) or maybe a Glossary (for example with https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra).